# Thread was being aborted in Response.Redirect

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm writing a class to validate sessions.

I get the this error

> Thread was being aborted

and on researching found that the way around it is to use the `false` parameter, but using that parameter does not redirect and instead allows the code after the redirect line to execute.
There must be something simple and fundamental here that I'm missing, below is my code.
It breaks in the `InvalidAccess()` method.

```
Public Sub New()
        CheckSessionCustomerID()
        If GotConnectionString() = False Then
            InvalidAccess()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function GotConnectionString() As Boolean
        GotConnectionString = False
        Try
            If PublicDBConnectionStringName.Trim = String.Empty Then
                GotConnectionString = False
            Else
                PublicConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(PublicDBConnectionStringName).ToString
                If PublicConnectionString.Trim <> String.Empty Then
                    GotConnectionString = True
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorLogging.LogError(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString(), PublicBBTCustomerID & "|" & ex.Message.ToString())
            GotConnectionString = False
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Sub CheckSessionCustomerID()
        Dim SessionEmployeeID As Integer
        Try
            If PublicTesting Then
                SessionEmployeeID = 1
            Else
                If IsNothing(HttpContext.Current.Session("EmployeeIDLoggedIn")) Then
                    InvalidAccess()
                ElseIf HttpContext.Current.Session("EmployeeIDLoggedIn").ToString = "0" Then
                    InvalidAccess()
                Else
                    SessionEmployeeID = Val(HttpContext.Current.Session("EmployeeIDLoggedIn"))
                    HttpContext.Current.Session("EmployeeIDLoggedIn") = SessionEmployeeID.ToString()
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            InvalidAccess()
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub InvalidAccess()
        Try
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/InvalidAccess.aspx")
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/Login.aspx?ID=" & PubliCustomerID & "&ID2=5")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The **Thread was being aborted** is completely normal when you redirect and wish to stop further execution of request.

In your `InvalidAccess` method remove `Try...Catch` block - it is meaningless.
The `Response.Redirect` will never throw an exception you are interested in.

It is not very clear what have you tried to achieve with this `try...catch` in your method.

Alternatively, you can use `false` parameter in `Response.Redirect`.

Comment: When I use the false parameter, it does not redirect. It continues code execution on that page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the false parameter on the Response.Redirect but then also you have to complete the request to stop execution if that's what you want:

```
Response.Redirect("/InvalidAccess.aspx", False)
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

http://www.blakepell.com/asp-net-avoid-threadabortexception-on-response-redirect